# How to call the member type without using the base class namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, derived-types

Base class:

```
namespace version {
namespace org {
    namespace com {
        namespce module {
            class Base {
                typedef std::function<void(int)> CallBack_t;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Child class:

```
namespace sun
{
class Child : public version::org::com::module::Base {
    bool function(int X_, CallBack_t cb_);
}
}
```

When I build the source, I get:

> error: no type named `CallBack_t` in sun::Child
>   it must be add the namespace before `CallBack_t`.

How to deal with this without using the Base Class namespace when calling member from the Base Class?

Comment: Making CallBack_t protected or public works in gcc and clang.

Comment: [access modifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)

Comment: Hmm from Danh's link "A class defined with the keyword class has private access for its members and its base classes by default." Which probably is  probably a good thing.